# R package: can't render formulas for html help pages using mathjaxr on Windows

Tags: r, formula

I'm writing an R package and I'm using the package **mathjaxr** to display formulas in the html help pages of R. This works perfectly on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) but not on Windows 10: After I installed my own package (from source) and loaded the package, I try to display the functions with `help("my_function")`. Now, on Linux the formula is perfectly displayed while on Windows I'm still seeing the plain code. I tried this on several machines and could reproduce this behaviour. To me, it looks like the javascript of mathjaxr is not executed on Windows(?).

My workflow to display formulas correctly on Linux:

1. Enter Latex formula code in roxygen comment of function file my_function.R:

   #' \mjdeqn{Latex_code_of_my_formula}
2. Call the MathJax macro by adding the following in the description section of my_function.R:

   #' \loadmathjax
3. Add `mathjaxr` to `Imports` in the `DESCRIPTION` file.
4. Add `mathjaxr` to `RdMacros` in the `DESCRIPTION` file.
5. Create a bundled package `my_package.tar.gz` by:

   devtools::build()
6. Switch to another machine and install the bundled package from source by:

   devtools::install_local("path/to/my_package.tar.gz")
7. Display help page of `my_function` by:

   help("my_function")

... which will result in a nice formula on Linux and plain code on Windows. Any idea what could be the reason for this behaviour? Thanks for replies in advance!

Comment: Maintainer of `mathjaxr` here. Confirmed under Windows 7 and 10. Seems to be due to the recent update of the package. More details here: https://github.com/wviechtb/mathjaxr/issues/6 Will look into this asap.